# Unreacheable Catch Block Issue

Tags: java, exception, unreachable-code

**Setup**

So I have two exceptions:

```
ProfileException extends Exception
UserException extends Exception
```

One of my helper class method throws these two exceptions togeather:

```
  Long getSomething() throes ProfileException, UserException
```

I invoke this method inside a try catch block like this.

```
try
{
   Long result = helperObj.getSomething();
}
catch(ProfileException pEx)
{
//Handle profile exception
}
catch(UserException uEx)
{
//Handle user exception
}
```

**Question**

1. Now I **NEED** to necessarily distinguish between those two exceptions thrown by the method and handle the exceptions separately depending on the type of exception being thrown.

However I get the following error.

```
Unreachable catch block for UserException. It is already handled by the catch block for ProfileException.
```

How can I distinguish and handle seperately depending on the type of exception thrown by that getSomething() method?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `throws` instead of `throes`?

Comment: @CommuSoft Pardon the typo!

Comment: What about switching the order of the catch blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both exceptions are in the same level in the heirarchy, you have to use like following

```
try {
   Long result = helperObj.getSomething();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  if (ex instanceOf ProfileException) {
      //Handle profile exception

  } else if (ex instanceOf UserException) {
     // Handle user exception

  }
}
```

Comment: I had that structure I think it did not work. The if(ex instanceof ProfileException) evaluated true for UserException.

Comment: @AnupSaumithri : then, `UserException` should extend `ProfileException`, otherwise, it can't be true

Comment: I am checking it again.

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that UserException extends ProfileException

Comment: Yep what you said is SPOT on. I changed it so that both extend from Exception. But the error stays neverthless.

Comment: @AnupSaumithri: Did you perform an entire clean and build. Some IDEs are lazy in compiling and will simply use older versions of the code that worked...

Comment: @CommuSoft, I think thats what was going on there. I made a clean build. I also changed the structure to the one shown below by --Kugathasan. I need to check again with your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite convinced that `UserException` probably `extends ProfileException`. If you modified it, it's probable that the IDE did not compiled the latest version (for instance because compiler errors occured). Therefore you can run a clean and build command (available in most popular IDEs).

You can simply resolve the problem by swapping the `catch` blocks:

```
try {
   Long result = helperObj.getSomething();
} catch(UserException uEx) {
    //Handle user exception
} catch(ProfileException pEx) {
    //Handle profile exception
}
```

Most IDE's however will always write `catch` blocks from specific types toward more general types in order to prevent such dead code.